# bash: Read file and print 1 word per line in stdout

Tags: bash, shell

So far my code is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for word in $(<$1)
do
    echo "$word"
done
```

which with input file containing (SP = space, TAB = tab and EOL - end of line) :

**The**< SP >**time**< SP >**has**< SP >**come,**< TAB >< SP >**the**< SP >**Walrus**< SP >**said,**
< SP >< SP >< SP >**to**< SP >**speak**< SP >**of**< SP >**many**< SP >**things:**< EOL >

Will output :

```
The
time
has
come,
the
Walrus
said,
to
speak
of
many
things:
```

I need my program to output with the functionality of a *word* being defined as any sequence of characters bounded by a *blank* or *TAB* character. So using the same input, i want my script to output:

```
The
time
has
come,

the
Walrus
said,


to
speak
of
many
things:
```

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It looks like both of your outputs already treat words as sequences of blank/tab separated characters, but the second output has on or two blank lines after words with commas - but that's not mentioned anywhere. Could you clarify?

Comment: @BenjaminW. As you can see from the input text, there are 3 spaces between "said," and "to", meaning that it would make extra gaps in the output for extra spaces. It's weird i know, im not 100% sure why it should be like this but oh well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the goal properly, you should be able to do it by using `tr` to turn spaces and tabs into line breaks:

```
#!/bin/bash

tr ' \t' '\n' <"$1"
```